# Flutter - await/async on a List - why does this only work when not using declarations?

Tags: flutter, async-await

Still new to Flutter :(. Can anyone help...

I have a class that stores a bunch of project information. One part of this is a list of topics (for push notification), which it grabs from a JSON file.

I apply a getter for the list of topics, and when getting it it calls an async function which will return a List

```
 Future<List<String>> _pntopics() async{
   final _json = await http.get(Uri.parse(_topicsUrl));    
   if (_json.statusCode == 200) {  
     return (jsonDecode(_json.body));
   }else {
     return [""];
   }
 }

 Future<List<String>> get topics => _pntopics();
```

In my main.dart file, it calls this value like so...

```
Future<List<String>> _topiclist = await projectvalues.topics;
```

The response is however empty, pressumably because it is a Future - so it is grabbing the empty value before it is filled.
But I can't remove the "Future" part from the async method, because asnc methods require a Future definition.

Then I decided to remove the declarations entirely:

```
  _pntopics() async{
     final _json = await http.get(Uri.parse(_topicsUrl));    
     if (_json.statusCode == 200) {  
       return (jsonDecode(_json.body));
     }else {
       return [""];
     }
   }

  get topics => _pntopics();
```

and in main.dart, a general declaration...

```
 var _topiclist = await projectvalues.topics;
```

...and this works!
So what declaration should I actually be using for this to work? I'm happy to not use declarations but we're always to declare everthing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return back `Future<List<String>>` return types to the function and the getter but for `_topicslist` you must use `var`, `final` or `List<String>` declaration because:

```dart
(await Future<T>) == T
```

i.e.

```dart
var _topiclist = await projectvalues.topics;    // The type of _topiclist is List<String>
final _topiclist = await projectvalues.topics;  // The type of _topiclist is List<String>
```

**UPDATE**

Your code should be:

```dart
Future<List<String>> _pntopics() async{
   final _json = await http.get(Uri.parse(_topicsUrl));    
   if (_json.statusCode == 200) {  
     return List<String>.from(jsonDecode(_json.body));
   }else {
     return <String>[""];
   }
 }
```

Doing this you force `_pnptopics` returns `List<String>` as `jsonDecode` returns `List<dynamic>`.

P.S. It is good practice do not use `dynamic` types where they can be changed to specified types.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that but I got [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(199)] Unhandled Exception: type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'FutureOr<List<String>>'  . In main.dart the  file is referenced as : List<String>? userTopics = prefs.getStringList('topics')  ?? [];   If I remove the "Future<List<String>>" from the function  and the getter, it works :S.

Comment: Typo..."In main.dart file the VARIABLE is referenced as..."

Comment: brilliant, thanks, that works. Of course - because it doesn't know what contents will be returned from the JSON file so it chooses dynamic as the default.